# print contents of fancybox

Tags: jquery, printing, fancybox

How can i print the text that is in a fancybox?

The format is terrible. From the left side, it goes waay too deep on the page, like this:

................................................ TEXT

The '...' represents spaces. stackoverflow removes them.

Also, from the top the text goes too deep down too. So how can i print whats in a fancybox exactly how its showed there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to generate a static HTML without any JavaScript. It gives you a much nicer preview of how it's going to look like when printed, and also a bit more printer-friendly.

Also, you can define stylesheets with `media="print"` attributes that could override some of the defaults of Fancybox.

Comment: I got a css for printing. something is still messing up with the style. but what did ya mean with your first 2 lines?

Comment: @Yustme Whatever you put in that Fancybox can be put somewhere else - in a basic HTML file for example, which is a *lot* more suited for printing.

Comment: i know that, its too complicated to explain why I did it like this, but you have to trust me on it. we have a FAQ in a update panel which you can filter on keywords. once you click on any of the results, you'll be leaving the page and thus losing the result. so showing it in a fancybox was the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint